# How construct `print` works?

Tags: php

I'm currently browsing issues for `Zend PHP 5 Certification Practice Test` and saw the following:

```
print print('5') + print('4');
// output
// 461

// or

echo '3' + '0.5' , print('2') + 1;
// output 
// 3.531
```

How does it work? Description and examples from http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php 
did not clarify anything…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`print` is not a function, it's a language construct. It always returns `1`, and its precedence is lower than arithmetic operators. So

```
print print('5') + print('4');
```

is equivalent to:

```
print (print ('5' + print '4'));
```

This executes the following steps:

1. `print 4` -- prints `4` and returns `1`.
2. Calculate `5 + 1`, which returns `6`.
3. `print 6` -- prints `6` and returns `1`
4. `print 1` -- prints `1` (also returns 1, but there's nothing receiving the result so irrelevant).

So

```
echo '3' + '0.5' , print('2') + 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
echo (3 + 0.5);
echo (print (2 + 1));
```

This executes the following steps:

1. Calculate `3 + 0.5`, which returns `3.5`
2. `echo 3.5`, which prints `3.5`
3. Calculate `2 + 1`, which returns `3`
4. `print 3`, which prints `3` and returns `1`.
5. `echo 1`, which prints `1`

Answer (score 2):

> print print('5') + print('4');

First it is printed/outputed `4` (right to left). Language construct `print` always returns `1` (outputs if echoed/printed), so `print('5') + 1` will output `6`. Then last print prints out return of construct `print`, which is `1` (as said before). So final output would be `461`.

---

> echo '3' + '0.5' , print('2') + 1;

In `echo` langauge construct, character `,` is concatenation. First `'3' + '0.5'` is outputed, which is `3.5`. Then again, as before, `print('2') + 1` will return `3`, and when echoing `print` will output `1`. So final output would be `3.531`.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the '4' print fires first, or the '5' print does *may* be implementation dependent. In this case, the '4' printed first, and its "print" returned a 1 which appears to have been added to '5' to get '6'. Finally, the '1' return code for the print('5') was output.

'3' + '0.5' gives '3.5'. After that (comma sequencing point), '2' + 1 was printed ('3'), and finally the print returned '1' return code.

I'm not sure I'd regard any of this dependence on sequencing and order of execution as good programming practice. If you need it for an exam, I suspect it may be more of a "gotcha" or warning of what *not* to do...

'print' and 'echo' behave somewhat differently, but I don't have my PHP texts at hand to describe exactly *how* they are different.

Comment: _implementation dependent_? There's only one PHP implementation, isn't there?

Comment: Differences between `print` and `echo`: `print` takes just one argument and returns 1. `echo` allows multiple arguments and returns nothing (it's a syntax error to use it in an expression).

Comment: In most languages, the order of execution is left to the compiler/interpreter author, and not defined by the language. Does PHP explicitly specify the order? I can't believe that PHP only allows one implementation.

Comment: I'm not saying that it only allows one implementation, just that there only _is_ one implementation.

Comment: The language specification is simply the documentation of that implementation.

Comment: I must disagree. A language spec _should_ come first, and implementation information (restrictions, etc.) is documented after the code is written. In the case of PHP, I understand that the development was very haphazard and ad hoc, and the first language spec was written long after the first implementation. But that's not the proper way to do things, and hopefully all future implementations will be based on the formal spec of the language.

Comment: That's how things work for languages with an independently defined standard. But that's not how PHP was developed. It was implemented and then documented. The same goes for Perl and Python. As time goes on, they make changes to the implementations, and then update the documentation to describe it.

Comment: In particular, if there's ever a disagreement between the documentation and the implementation, the designers could just as easily classify it as an error in the documentation, rather than fix the implementation.

Comment: Once a language standard has been made public, I would certainly hope that no one pulls a stunt like that (changing a language standard to conform to an implementation). What would happen to other implementations that were done properly and _do_ conform to the standard?

Comment: If there were a standard for PHP that would be true. But there isn't one, there's just the one implementation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `print` always returns 1. And secondly it can be called without parenthesis. And lastly the [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) has to be taken into account.

With this your first statement can be dissected into the following arithmetic structure:

1. Evaluate `print('4')`: output 4 and return 1
2. Evaluate `print('5') + 1`: output 6 and return 1
3. Evaluate `print`: output 1

The same works with your second statement, but here you must take the aformentioned operator precedence into account, `+` has a higher one than `,`:

1. Evaluate `echo 3 + 0.5`: output 3.5
2. Evaluate `print('2') + 1`: output 3 and output the return value of `print()`, 1